# How do I get Unity to launch "Log File Viewer" as root?

Tags: 11.04, unity, sudo, root, log

By default, "Log File Viewer" is not launched from Unity as root in Ubuntu 11.04. This is pretty useless, as most of the log files are only readable by root.

How can I change this behavior so that it launches as root?

Comment: Can you give some examples of files you can't view? I'm on 11.04, on the console and logged in as a sudoer, and I can view all log files.

Comment: @Jo-Erlend When I launch 'log file viewer', I get a message about not having permission to open "/var/log/btmp". Not surprising as that file does not belong to the "adm" group and neither do I. Other log files are accessible.
It's strange, it's a few days ago now, but I thought I'd tried other log files before and failed.. Perhaps it's to do with an update that required a re-boot? I had a number of pending updates and have re-booted between now and then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup and modify /usr/share/applications/gnome-system-log.desktop; change line:

```
Exec=gnome-system-log
```

to:

```
Exec=gksu --description /usr/share/applications/gnome-system-log.desktop /usr/bin/gnome-system-log
```

Downside is that it will now always ask for a password.

Answer (score 1):

You could also install a similar utility called **glogg** -
It would make it easier to run as sudo